# Is there a bijective map between subgroups of a finite abelian group and subgroups of its dual?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, characters

> Let $(G,+)$ be a finite abelian group, $\widehat{G}$ the dual group of $G$ (i.e. the set of homomorphisms from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}^*$).
> If $X$ is a subset of $G$, we define $X^{\bot}$ as the subgroup of $\widehat{G}$ whose elements are the trivial characters on $X$, that is:
> \begin{equation}
> X^{\bot}=\{\chi \in \widehat{G};\: X \subset \ker(\chi)\}
> \end{equation}
> Let $K$ be any subgroup of $\widehat{G}$ and if $Y$ is a subset of $\widehat{G}$, let’s write $Y^°$ for the following subgroup of $G$:
> \begin{equation}
> Y^°= \bigcap_{\chi \in Y} \ker(\chi)
> \end{equation}
>
> Show that the following applications
> \begin{equation}
> \displaystyle H \longmapsto H^{\bot}\: \: \text{and} \: \: K \longmapsto K^°
> \end{equation}
> are two reciprocal bijections between the subgroups of $G$ and the subgroups of $\widehat{G}$.

My idea (but it was apparently a bad idea) was to consider the following bijective map , call it $f$, that takes a subgroup $H$ of $G$ to the set of characters of $\widehat{G}$ whose kernel contains $H$ (i.e. $H^{\bot}$):
\begin{equation}
f(H)=\{\chi \in \widehat{G};\: \chi(h)=1, \: \forall h \in H \}.
\end{equation}
Then consider the inverse bijective map, say $g$, defined as:
\begin{equation}
g\big(f(H)\big)=\{g \in G; \: \chi(g)=1,\: \forall \chi \in f(H)\}
\end{equation}
We first show that this set contains $H$ and by an inclusion reversing argument, that this set is $H$ itself !
We conclude that $g \circ f$ is the identity map. We proceed the same way for $f \circ g$.
I thought it could work but it doesn’t because the map $K \longmapsto K^°$ defined in the exercise is totally different from mine: it is defined on any subgroup $K$ in the dual group $\widehat{G}$ and sends $K$ to $K^°$.
I’m really confused about that. Any help would be appreciated.
Many thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but doesn't the statement *give* you the bijections? You want to verify that for every subgroup $H$ of $G$ you have $(H^{\perp})^*=H$ and that for every subgroup $K$ of the dual you have $(K^*)^{\perp}=K$.